# Snap cursor to specific point of draggable element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am dragging thumbnails from one DIV to another and attempting to imitate the "snap-to-a-grid" feature used in AutoCAD , Adobe Illustrator, many other graphics-editing software, etc.

**Question 1:**
How could I get the pointer to snap to the 0,0 position (x and y position) of the image I am clicking for dragging, regardless of where the pointer was on the image when clicked?

When I click to drag an image, the pointer sticks to where the pointer was when clicked and the coordinates I am going to track will be for the pointer.

I tried this:

```
    cursor: url(mycustomcursor.png) 0 0 , auto;
```

and the custom pointer appears but doesn't snap to 0,0 as hoped.

**Question 2:**
How can I get my image to stick precisely where dropped in a DIV and return the offset in pixels from the top/left of the DIV it is being dropped into?

I don't know if the cursor position when dragging is relevant but when I drop my image with the following script the image shifts twice the distance I expect of in other words the offsetX value, doubled. I have added the script below and had to edit out a bunch of (hopefully) non-relevant script like CSS for colors, borders, etc. I am also only working with the X-coordinates for simplicity in testing.

```
<div style='overflow:scroll;text-align:left;position:absolute;width:90%;  height:180px;' ondrop='drop(event)' ondragover='allowDrop(event)'>
    <img id='image_1234' src='image_path/image.png' style='position:absolute;height:100px;' draggable='true' ondragstart='drag(event)'>
</div>
<div id='panel_frame' style='width:600px;height:300px;' ondrop='drop(event)' ondragover='allowDrop(event)'>
</div>

function allowDrop(evAllow) {
    evAllow.preventDefault();
}

function drag(evDrag) {
    evDrag.dataTransfer.setData('text', evDrag.target.id);
}

function drop(evDrop) {
    evDrop.preventDefault();
    var dropData = evDrop.dataTransfer.getData('text',evDrop.id);       
    evDrop.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(dropData));
    var offsetLeft = evDrop.clientX + 'px';
    document.getElementById(dropData).style.left = offsetLeft;
}
```

I am testing in Firefox. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You may want to look into `element.offsetTop` and `element.offsetLeft`.  Depending on your layout technique you could place the cursor at [offsetTop, offsetLeft]  which should give you the top left corner position on the screen.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop

Comment: offsetTop appears to act the same. I was thinking that I may need to 1-get the coordinates of the upper left corner of the image, then 2-get coordinates of cursor when clicked, then 3-somehow shift the cursor the difference. How could you shift a cursor?

Comment: Did you manage to get either of these questions answered? @John